# Getting intent extras from just one class

Tags: java, android, object, android-intent

Is there a way I can just receive intent extras from just one class? For example I have two activities that use intent to open the third activity. Now I just want one of the first two to pass extras so I can receive it in the third activity.

I have implemented everything but it crashes because when I open third activity from second one that doesn't put extras, it crashes my app.

To picture it more clearly:

- Activity 1: passes intent extras
- Activity 2: doesn't pass any extras
- Activity 3: receives intent extras

Both Activity 1 and 2 use intent to start Activity 3, but I just need extras from activity 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a null check

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
if(data != null)
{
    String one = intent.getString("data_one", null); // use your data type
}
else
{
    // No extra received
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks :)
For someone reading this, for Bundle to work, you must build for API12 or put Annotation @TargetApi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something as simple as this?

```
if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
  //presume this is Activity1, get extras that we need
  ...
} else {
  //any non-Activity1 activity launched it
}
```